# Function only works how I want it with print, not return

Tags: python, string, function, printing, return

this functions takes a string and an integer 'n', and breaks down the string into 'n' lines. 
It works with 'print' but it outputs 'None' in the end.

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    for i in range(0, len(string), max_width):
        print(string[i:i+max_width])
```

I understand it's because there is no 'return' but if I replace it with return the output is wrong. I've tried changing the code but to no avail.

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    for i in range(0, len(string), max_width):
        return string[i:i+max_width]
```

Can someone please explain how to fix it, and especially, why it happens??

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "wrong", what do you mean? Can you write one example?

Comment: if you return, it breaks the loop... what do you want to return? a list?

Comment: For, instance, if you input wrap(aabb, 2) it should output:
(line1) aa
(line 2) bb
but it out puts only 'aa'

Comment: try using `yield` instead of return, see if that gives what you are looking for.

Comment: `yield` outputs `<generator object wrap at...>`

Comment: @Sergi try calling it like `for s in wrap(my_string, desired_width): print(s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write it like below your function will not stop after i = 0, but continue until the end. Note that the function now returns a list of strings. You need something to hold together all the outputs. A list is the simplest of such 'containers'.

Your original function only returned just the first string. A `return` interrupts the for loop.

```py
def wrap(string, max_width):
    return [string[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0, len(string), max_width)]
```

To see what happens, we can run the following code:

```py
wrapped_string = wrap ("aabbcc", 2)
print(wrapped_string)
for s in wrapped_string:
    print (s)
```

which prints

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
aa
bb
cc
```

Here is a version with a generator (using `yield`):

```py
def generate_wrap(string, max_width):
    for i in range(0, len(string), max_width):
        yield string[i:i+max_width]

wrapped_string = generate_wrap("aabbcc", 2)
print(wrapped_string)
for s in wrapped_string:
    print (s)
```

This prints:

```
<generator object generate_wrap at 0x039B8230>
aa
bb
cc
```

A generator is a special function that creates something similar to a list, but it generates the values one at a time. Also, you have to create the generator again if you want to use it a second time. Generators are important for very long lists, including never ending lists (e.g. generating the primes).

Comment: What do you mean with the 'None' at the end?

Comment: If you want to use the output, you have to keep it in some sort of 'container'. How else can you refer to it later?